Insecure Deployment: Path Normalization Conflict - Fortify
The Fortify Webinspect scan reported the following issue for our web application which deployed on the IIS server. I am not sure how to handle this on the IIS server's web.config, the below picture shows the issue detail we got it from the report. We are able to reproduce the "Execution" section as mention below. I really appreciate your help on this.


OWASP TP 10 2017: A6-Security Misconfiguration and OWASP TP 10 2021: A05-Security Misconfiguration, although not the same year, both point to the same problem type: Security Misconfiguration. It is recommended that you see which description fits your situation according to https://owasp.org/Top10/A05_2021-Security_Misconfiguration/.  And I don't know much about Fortify Webinspect, and it's not an official Microsoft software either. You can consult the software operator to learn more.
